# OWIN hosting as webapplication in IIS 7 (OWIN Startup not getting called inside virtual directory)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, owin

I have a Owin middleware authentication project deployed as a web-application in IIS 7.5
but the problem is that Startup.cs is not getting called.

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Authorization.Startup))]

namespace Authorization
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            //Logger.Write(string.Format("Authorizations->frist Configuration "), LoggingCategoryNames.PRESENTATION_LAYER_LOGGING_CATEGORY);
            ConfigureAuth(app);
        }
    }
}
```

this code is not getting executed.
when we deploy it as a root level website, everything works fine.

So where are we going wrong and what can be done to make it work.
We cannot deploy our authentication project as a seperate website, it has to be a webapplication only.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found something similar. My `Configuration` method was running but the Authentication middleware (OpenIdConnect in this instance) did not seem to be executing in the Owin pipeline when hosted as a child Web Application. It worked fine when hosted as a root website.

Before delving any deeper into debugging the pipeline itself I tried a couple of things that I have seen cause issues when using other token services (ADFS for one). And sure enough it turned out to be one of them.

The old trailing slash issue.

My OpenIdConnect config in the client application looked like this before

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
{
    Authority = "https://idserver/identity",
    ClientId = "Client",
    RedirectUri = "https://clients/mvcclientapp"
    ...
});
```

And the client would just not process the incoming token. The middleware didn't seem to be executing within the pipeline at all.

I added an extra "/" to the end of the RedirectUrl and it started to work.

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
{
    Authority = "https://idserver/identity",
    ClientId = "Client",
    RedirectUri = "https://clients/mvcclientapp/"
    ...
});
```

This was NOT required when hosted in IIS as a root website.

Comment: Unbelievable! We found the same thing. Thanks for the fix. For us, we would simply get redirected back to our application, but federated authentication wouldn't happen.